# Access to oldChild by replaceChild with getElementsClassName, Javascript, DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, xhtml, getelementsbyclassname

How can I get access to the old Node and replace it?

My XHTML has this structure:

```
<table id="output">
 <tr>
   <td>Sometext</td>
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...<td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="CLASSNAME">
   <td class="ElemKat">text</td>
   <td class="ELEM">...</td>
   <td class="EL">...</td>
 </tr> 
  <tr class="CLASSNAME">
   <td class="ElemKat">text2</td>
   <td class="ELEM">s</td>
   <td class="EL">sss</td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

I have so many classes, because the elements are create dynamically and so the IDs are not a variant.

And the function, in which the error shows up (error as a comment):

```
var sort=function(cmpFunc) {

    var table=document.getElementById("output");
    var kat=document.getElementsByClassName("ElemKat");
    var elem_kat=new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<kat.length; i++) {
            elem_kat.push(kat[i]); 
        }
        var elem_kat_old=new Array();
        elem_kat_old=elem_kat;
        elem_kat.sort(cmpFunc);

   for(var j=0; j<elem_kat.length; j++) {
    //table=elem_kat_old[j].parentNode; ->No error,but no change in the output
    table.replaceChild(elem_kat[j],elem_kat_old[j]); //Node was not found
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `replaceChild` works on grandchildren. Also, what is `table` in the function? There is no element in the XHTML with id="output".

Comment: @MrLister In my XHTML I have different things, I only wanted to explain the structure, that`s relevant for my question, I have XHTML document with a formular, you write the data there and  the text shows up in a table <table id="output", the next thing, I have to sort this table by specific criterions,so I make this thing with <tr class="Classname">,because I dont want that the first row takes part of the sorting Algorithm, I will update my code in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `elem_kat_old = elem_kat;`, try this:

`elem_kat_old = elem_kat.slice(0)`

Assigning an array to another array makes it so that whatever you do to one array, happens to the other array. This isn't quite assignment by reference, but I am not 100% sure of the proper Javascript term for it.

Comment: But so this is my first element of the array. JavaScript Array slice() Method-start:  Required. An integer that specifies where to start the selection (The first element has an index of 0).

Comment: That doesn't matter. You just want to make a clone of the entire array. `0` is the starting element, so it will make a clone of the array from 0 to its max length, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I dont need to change the elem_kat_old after changing the another array- I need the opposite thing-have it as a copy of my old information,of my old order before the sorting. I thought, that I could use it for the access to my oldChild

Comment: That's exactly what that code does. Please try it and post if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it,in the first case the same error:Node was not found. When I add this,what I commented in the question table=elem_kat_old[j].parentNode; everything mixes insanely and only my first element is shown on place(in his old order) my newChild doesnt show up